# Remove white space between left and right side in the Slick thumbnail Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

I created a slick slider with thumbnails in which I need to `selectFocus` slide in either center or right side last one. I am using the below code but it doesn't work. If I will set `centerMode:true` and `infinite: true`, it's has a white gap between the left and right side

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider img_gallery_single">
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
            </figure>
        </div>
    <div>
    <figure>
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/9.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/10.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider img_gallery_thumb_nav">
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/9.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/10.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>



<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.img_gallery_single').slick({
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    arrows: false,
                    fade: false,
                    infinite: true,
                    useTransform: true,
                    speed: 400,
                    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.18, 1)',
                });

                $('.img_gallery_thumb_nav')
                    .on('init', function(event, slick) {
                        $('.img_gallery_thumb_nav .slick-slide.slick-current').addClass('is-active');
                    })
                    .slick({
                        autoSlidesToShow: true,
                        //slidesToShow: 5,
                        slidesToScroll:1,
                        dots: false,
                        focusOnSelect: true,
                        infinite: true,
                        centerMode:true,
                        arrows: false,
                        variableWidth: true,
                    });

                $('.img_gallery_single').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
                    $('.img_gallery_thumb_nav').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide);
                    var currrentNavSlideElem = '.img_gallery_thumb_nav .slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + currentSlide + '"]';
                    $('.img_gallery_thumb_nav .slick-slide.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
                    $(currrentNavSlideElem).addClass('is-active');
                });

                $('.img_gallery_thumb_nav').on('click', '.slick-slide', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var goToSingleSlide = $(this).data('slick-index');

                    $('.img_gallery_single').slick('slickGoTo', goToSingleSlide);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I don't think there's an `autoSlidesToShow` option for Slick. If you're using `centerMode` you will need to use an odd number of slides for your `slidesToShow` value.

Comment: AutoslidesToshow options use for an auto-set number of thumbnails as per screen resolutions